# Stack overflow visual C++, potentially array size?

Tags: c++, arrays, stack, overflow

As far as I know, this isn't caused by an infinite recursion.

The program functioned correctly with smaller arrays (it is an audio editor). Now I have increased functionality to allow for larger arrays (up to 5 minutes of audio, 26460000 pieces of 16bit data ~50mb).

Since increasing the array's size I am receiving stack overflow errors on one particular function, where it should reverse the playback of an input file by writing the array into a new array backwards, then overwriting the original array. I'm guessing as each array could be up to 50MB this may be where the problem lies:

```
//initialise temporary new array to place samples in
short signed int reverse_data[max_number_samples];  

for (i=0; i<track_samples; i++)
{  //puts data from sound_data into reverse_data backwards.
  reverse_data[(max_number_samples-1)-i]=sound_data[i];    
}

for (i=0; i<track_samples; i++)    
{     //now overwrites sound_data with the data in reverse_data
  sound_data[i]=reverse_data[i];
}
```

I'm fairly new to C++, and programming in general, and am unsure of what the errors I get during debug are really telling me.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm sure there's a simple enough solution (I've read stuff involving 'heaps' but I'm not confident of what a'heap' really is).

Comment: Are you sure `reverse_data[(max_number_samples-1)-i]` is correct? You are writing data only to the end part of the `reverse_data` array, but than you read them from the beginning.

Comment: ah, I didn't see this comment. You are correct, but then I used another loop to search for the start of the audio, and only write the data from the start of the audio to the end. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vlad [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10536508/8747), don't allocate 50MB on the stack.

But, the point is moot because you don't need to allocate *any* data. Try replacing your entire code fragment with a single call to [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse):

```
std::reverse(&sound_data[0], &sound_data[track_samples]);
```

---

*Postscript*: Don't forget to `#include <algorithm>`.

Answer (score 6):

You should not allocate large data structures on stack, because the stack's size is bounded. Allocate it on heap.

Even better, you should avoid manual allocation and use `std::vector`, which will care for the memory allocation itself. As a bonus, you won't need to care about deallocation. (And this is the modern C++ way.)

By the way, if `max_number_samples` is big, you should perhaps allocate only as much as you need:

```
std::vector<short int> reverse_data(track_samples);
```

(the rest of your code stays as it is).

Edit:
Even better idea: you can reverse your array in place, without copying into an additional array! Just go from index 0 to the half size and swap the `i`th and `(size - 1 - i)`th items:

```
for (i=0; i < track_samples/2; i++)
{
    std::swap(sound_data[i], sound_data[track_samples-1-i]);
}
```

Comment: +1 ...and do not use recursion for such large amount of data!

Comment: Ah thanks, so the issue lies in the size of the arrays, as i expected!

How would I initialise my arrays on heap, rather than stack?

Comment: Re: "allocate only as much as you need": If `max_number_samples` if bigger than `track_samples`, then `reverse_data[(max_number_samples-1)-i]` will crash when `i==0`.

Comment: Even betterer idea: [`std::reverse(&sound_data[0], &sound_data[track_samples]);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/)

Comment: @Rob: I assume it's a mistake in the OP's code: he wanted actually `track_samples` instead of `max_number_samples`.

Comment: @Rob: is there such a standard function? My C++ is rusty :( Would you mind posting this as a separate answer?

Comment: max_number_samples is bigger or equal to track_samples. 

max_number_samples refers to the array created to hold potentially 5 minutes, whereas track_samples has searched for the end of the audio and refers to how many samples will be written to the output pcm.

when trying to initialise the vector, i receive error:

    error C2039: 'vector' : is not a member of 'std'

Comment: @holmes321: try `#include <vector>` at the beginning