# Visual C++ Array Size Crash

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, crash, stack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack overflow visual C++, potentially array size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536479/stack-overflow-visual-c-potentially-array-size)

This code is simply meant to read values from a binary file into the array DataBuffer.  When the size of DataBuffer is greater than or equal to 515000, it simply crashes.  I am developing this in Visual C++ 2010 on Windows 7.  The function cbFileRead() is something whose source code I can not access.  cbFileRead() expects DataBuffer to be of the type USHORT*.

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf()
#include "cbw.h"    // cbFileRead()

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // Declarations
    char* FileName = argv[1];
    long FirstPoint = 0;
    long NumPoints;

    // Set data collection sizes
    const long chunkSize = 515000;
    NumPoints = chunkSize; // Number of points to be read into mem
    WORD DataBuffer[chunkSize-1];

    // Get data
    cbFileRead(FileName, FirstPoint, &NumPoints, DataBuffer);

    printf("Completed on data point %d whose value is %d\n", NumPoints, DataBuffer[chunkSize-1]);

    return 0;
}
```

What reasons are there for this crashing?  I would expect the array size to be able to go much higher.

Comment: You typically have a pretty small stack by default. I'd use `std::vector` instead

Comment: That looks like C, not C++ ? Why is it tagged as C++ ?

Comment: Stack in Windows is around 1MB (or 2), IIRC.

Comment: @PaulR: Because it's being compiled by a C++ compiler.

Comment: @DougRamsey: I have over a gigabyte of free memory.  I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @thoughtadvances you almost certainly don't have a multi-gigabyte stack. It's normally only a megabyte or so.

Comment: @thoughtadvances: You could have over 1TB of RAM free...yet your code will still crash if the stack size for the thread is not large enough.

Comment: @thoughtadvances: It doesn't matter how much free memory you have. STack size has limitations of its own. Basically, there are two problems in your code: 1) large buffer on stack, 2) buffer of size `chunkSize-1`. Why `-1`? Where did `-1` come from?

Comment: I understand the stack problem.  Dough asked about memory being taken up by other programs.

Comment: @PaulR, Probably because of `const long chunkSize` usage in array declaration! ;)

Comment: @Ajay: OK, so it's C99 - it's still not C++ though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The default stack reservation size used by the linker is 1 MB. To
>   specify a different default stack reservation size for all threads and
>   fibers, use the STACKSIZE statement in the module definition (.def)
>   file.

[Microsoft Dev Center - Thread Stack Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Or you can allocate the memory dynamically with the `new` keyword.

Comment: Thanks.  I just discovered that `new` is capable of doing this.

Answer (score 4):

The `printf()` is going beyond the end of the array `DataBuffer`, as it has `chunksize - 1` elements so the last element is `chunksize - 1 - 1`. The function `cbFileRead()` is (possibly) misinformed of the number of elements in `DataBuffer` also.

EDIT:

**As others have already stated**, the default stack size is 1MB. The size of the `DataBuffer` array is `2 * 515000` which equals `1030000`, which leaves `18576` free bytes on the stack. `cbFileRead()` could easily be declaring a large buffer on the stack for reading from file. As suggested by everyone else, allocate the `DataBuffer` on the heap using `new[]` (and `delete[]` to free) or use `vector<WORD>`.

Comment: +1, that's a problem too (didn't scroll his code enough!).

Comment: Thanks.  FirstPoint = 0, so I think `cbFileRead()` is getting the correct numbers.  I want `chunkSize` elements, so they are stored in an array of `chunkSize() - 1`.  Because the array is also null indexed, the last element of the array is then `chunkSize()-2`.  Is that right?

Comment: @thoughtadvances, but the array was declared as having `chunkSize - 1` elements. If it has `chunkSize` elements then valid indexes are from `0` to `chunkSize - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Your stack size may not be large enough to handle local data of that size (assuming this is what you mean by "crash"):

```
// use dynamic allocation instead of stack local
WORD *DataBuffer = new WORD[chunkSize];

cbFileRead(FileName, FirstPoint, &NumPoints, DataBuffer);

// ...use DataBuffer...

// deallocate DataBuffer when done
delete[] DataBuffer;
```

Comment: +1 returned as this a probable cause.

Answer (score 1):

On most platforms, including Windows, local variables are stored on a stack, which has a limited size - in this case, it looks like it's around 1MB. There's probably a way to increase that size if you really need to, but it would be better to allocate large arrays dynamically:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<WORD> DataBuffer(chunkSize); // guessing that "chunkSize-1" was an error

cbFileRead(FileName, FirstPoint, &NumPoints, &DataBuffer[0]);

printf("Completed on data point %d whose value is %d\n", 
       NumPoints, DataBuffer[chunkSize-1]);
```

Note that, if the array size is actually supposed to be `chunkSize-1`, then the last element would be `DataBuffer[chunkSize-2]`, since arrays are indexed from zero.